# How to validate and get form working?

Tags: forms

I am trying to validate my form and make it writeToFile when submitted (.txt file) but I can't seem to get it right, searched Google for help but still nothing happens when submit button clicked.

Name: 
    

Business:

Telephone:

Comment:

---

The Script I tried:

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["commentform"]["fname"]["fcomment"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
```

{

```
  alert("You must enter a Name and Comment");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( document.commentform.fname.value == "" )
   {
     alert("You must enter a Name");
     return false;
  }
if( document.commentform.fcomment.value == "" )
   {
     alert("You must enter a Comment");
     return false;
  }
```